# bundling and publishing an NPM library. Is it common to resolve all dependencies and include them into the bundle?

Tags: javascript, npm, bundle, rollup, npm-publish

I've been tasked with the development of a NPM package with a custom component (in this case a react component) that makes uses of other dependencies such as plate, slate, etc.

I'm in the process of preparing the output **dist** but it's not clear to me what the best practices are when doing so:
Should all dependencies be resolved and bundled into a big .js file or this can be ignored ? (I'm using rollup resolve here). I'm afraid this would produce a huge file including the source of all the dependencies but as I stated I'm really not familiar with the process...

In the other hand, is it common NOT to resolve such dependencies and let the final consumer of the component do so ? (I'm only assuming here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all about pros and cons... and what is possible. For example React itself can only exist in one version in an entire project so you should never include that.

Dependencies that are needed but not included should be added as `peerDependencies` in your `package.json` and it is the responsibility of the consumer to download them. The downside with including dependencies (as `dependencies` so that they will be downloaded automatically by the consumer) is that the bundle of the consumer might be bigger than it needs to be. Here you should take into account who will consume it; is it for internal use in your organization or public use? Do you know anything about the context it will be used in? It's best not to include dependencies since it will contribute to smaller resulting bundle for the consumer but if it's unlikely that the depending dependencies are present in the build environment of the consumer, you might as well add it to your package. The situation that you want to avoid is that your package includes a different version of the same package that the consumer is already using; then the resulting bundle may contain two versions of a lot of code that could potentially be reduced to one version (if the version used by the consumer and by your package are compatible). Of course all of this potentially becomes worse and more likely with large common dependencies than with small uncommon dependencies.

An example: in my organization we use Material-UI. We have a package with React components using Material-UI which we consume in other projects. Since Material-UI will always be present in the projects, it's bad practice to include it in the package, even though it will place a higher responsibility on the consumers (us) to align different versions of the package with whatever version of Material-UI that we're using in the applicable project. Given another consumption context, including it in the package might have made more sense.

According to me, you should never bundle your package since it makes tree shaking more complicated for the consumer. This applies to esm packages (cjs is not tree-shakeable). In cjs on the other hand it's devastating with bundled packages since it prevents the consumer from making more specific imports to avoid importing a lot of unused code, e.g.

```
import Comp from "package/Component"
```

instead of

```
import { Comp } from "package"
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your explanation. I will deeply investigate on the concepts you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost never a good reason to embed dependencies inside library bundles. That's how you end up with multiple copies of dependencies in web apps. At best, web apps' bundles end up being unnecessarily bloated. At worst, dependencies that break when they're duplicated (e.g. React) yield all sorts of unexpected behaviour.

The surefire way to prevent dependency duplication is to avoid bundling libraries at all. If you inspect your `node_modules` folder in any of your web app projects, you'll likely find numerous third-party dependencies that aren't bundled. And their lack of bundling doesn't have an impact on your web app. That proves that library bundling is pointless.

Comment: There is definitely a use case for bundling dependencies. If you are working in a monorepo and one of the packages that you depend on is not supposed to be published to npm then you have no other option to bundle it!

Comment: @Elmer that's simply not true. Intra-repo dependencies need to be transpiled, but they don't need to be bundled. Even if they're bundled, they should not include their dependencies; They should only import them. The app's bundler will resolve the imports and bundle transitive dependencies as required. If you look in your `node_modules`, you may notice that some third-party dependencies aren't even bundled, even when they have dependencies. I work in two large frontend monorepos with intra-repo dependencies and we don't bundle any of the libraries.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I have a situation here where this is simply true. I know that there are plenty of cases where this is not true, but there are cases where it is true.